# Why is 'Gradle-aware Make' automatically added to my custom run/debug configuration after restarting Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.3

I created my custom run configuration and this work

[image]

but after restart Android Studio, i can see Gradle-aware Make, it`s very bed for me

[image]

How to remove it, I don't want to delete it manually every time after restart Android Studio

---

Android Studio stable version 3.3.2

Comment: Try to add flag at Android studio's VM option file-https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/77840239#comment3

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config.html#customize_vm

Comment: @Chandralal well, as I can export VM option for all my team?